# Is there a way to assign 3 borders (say left, right & top) all at once instead of individually?

Tags: css

If you're setting all the borders to be the same, you can simply do something like `border: 1px solid #DDD`. Now, if I need to do only 3 of them, I'm forced to write each one out like  `border-left: 1px solid #DDD`, `border-top: 1px solid #DDD`, etc. Is there a way I can combine them into one line? Something like `border-{left,right,top}: 1px solid #DDD`

The simplest two line option I have is to first set all borders and turn one of them off. But I reset all borders to zero at the start of the script, so this is kind of redundant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

3 lines

```
div {
  border-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 1px 1px 0;
}
```

2 lines

```
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-left: 0;
}
```

See http://css-tricks.com/three-sided-border/

Answer (score 2):

I guess there is no solution for this. The short hand technique for border attribute is not available to set multiple borders.

you can try this:

```
border: #ffffff solid;
border-width: 3px 2px 1px 0;
```